# Установка laravel или yii2

Tags: php, yii2, laravel

Всем привет. Я начинающий php-шник и решил изучить какой нибудь фреймвор. Решил yii2 или laravel. Но почитав документации понял что чтобы устоновить на сервер нужно скачать какой то composer (первый раз об этой штуки слышу) и вводить команды какие то на установку. Я думал будет легче, тупа скачаю архив и распакую и буду инклудить. Так вот можно ли установить laravel или yii2 (или другой популярный фреймворк) на обычный php хостинг?

Comment: @Максим Ленский задаю конкретнаю проблему. Не могу устонавить laravel на простой хостинг. В гугле все экзамплы на приватных серверах. Если знаете статьи поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: @МаксимЛенский хочу на хостинг себе установить (обычный хостинг). На компе же для изучения есть локалка опенсервер.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский отвечаю. да на комп

Comment: теперь заархивируйте , базу в дамп и перенесите на хостинг

Comment: а если хостинг не shared то там есть терминал

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFjXzWkfUPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы решили заняться изучением Laravel, то, я бы начал с изучения https://laravel.ru/
Там, можно почитать много крайне полезного (документация и примеры) и всякого интересного (статьи).

Кроме этого, не спешите брать хостинг. Для работы с Laravel, достаточно простого ноутбука, с 4Gb оперативки (лучше, конечно больше) - на нем можно развернуть homestead, решение, которое идеально поможет Вам разрабатывать решение, приближенное к боевым условиям.

Не понравится homestead - ставьте OpenServer или еще что-то подобное (да, я делаю предположение, что у вас ОС Windows).

Касаемо командной строки, тут уж так повелось, Вам так или иначе придется это изучить, так как там много вещей, что значительно упростят вашу жизнь.

- Homestead - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/homestead
- valet (если у Вас Mac) - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/valet
- Установка - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/installation

Composer - пакетный менеджер для php, он уже идет установленный на Homestead и вы его просто используете. В интернете много разной информации по нему.